# Convert data from many rows to many columns

Tags: r, reshape

I have data that comes out of a DB in a normalized way with a field for year, state, and value.

I would like to do analysis on the data and need it formatted where each year is a field and not a record.So I would like the data where each record is a state and then there's a field for each year and each value for those fields are the value for that year and that state.

Is there a command for doing this?

So I have:

```
State  Year  Value  
   KY  1998     56  
   KY  1997     78  
   IL  1998     48  
   IL  1997     72
```

and I want:

```
State  1997_value  1998_value  
   KY          78          56  
   IL          72          48
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want to use the `reshape()` function.

```
reshape(data, idvar="State", timevar="Year", direction="wide")
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use the reshape *package*, created by the inimitable Hadley Wickham:

```
library(reshape)

tuna<-melt(data,id.vars=c("State","Year"))

cast(tuna,State~Year~variable)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can even combine the melt and cast lines into one call to the recast function.

```
ds <- data.frame(State = c("KY", "KY", "IL", "IL"), 
Year = c(1998, 1997, 1998, 1997), 
Value = c(56, 78, 48, 72))

library(reshape)
recast(ds, State ~ Year, id.var = c("State", "Year"))
```

Comment: In this case, the data is already in molten form, so you can just skip the melt step.